# Laravel Import: file_put_contents(...): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, excel, laravel, image, import

I'm trying to import an Excel file with an image on it. However, I came across this error.

> file_put_contents(images/detail_pengajuan/16553943431.jpg): failed to
> open stream: No such file or directory

I have already tried clearing all caches and deleting the config.php in the bootstrap folder, but still to no avail. I also don't see the image stored in the `images/detail_pengajuan` folder. Below are the codes

**Import.php**

```
namespace App\Imports;

use App\SubmissionDetail;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Row;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\OnEachRow;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\MemoryDrawing;

class SubmissionDetailImport implements OnEachRow, WithHeadingRow
{
    protected $id;

    function __construct($id) {
            $this->id = $id;
    }

    public function onRow(Row $row)
    {
        $row = $row->toArray();
        $i = 0;
        $spreadsheet = IOFactory::load(request()->file('file'));
        foreach ($spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getDrawingCollection() as $drawing) {
            if ($drawing instanceof MemoryDrawing) {
                ob_start();
                call_user_func(
                    $drawing->getRenderingFunction(),
                    $drawing->getImageResource()
                );
                $imageContents = ob_get_contents();
                ob_end_clean();
                switch ($drawing->getMimeType()) {
                    case MemoryDrawing::MIMETYPE_PNG :
                        $extension = 'png';
                        break;
                    case MemoryDrawing::MIMETYPE_GIF:
                        $extension = 'gif';
                        break;
                    case MemoryDrawing::MIMETYPE_JPEG :
                        $extension = 'jpg';
                        break;
                }
            } else {
                $zipReader = fopen($drawing->getPath(), 'r');
                $imageContents = '';
                while (!feof($zipReader)) {
                    $imageContents .= fread($zipReader, 1024);
                }
                fclose($zipReader);
                $extension = $drawing->getExtension();
            }
        }
        $myFileName = time() .++$i. '.' . $extension;
        file_put_contents('images/detail_pengajuan/' . $myFileName, $imageContents);

        $submissionDetails = SubmissionDetail::firstOrCreate(
            ['submission_id' => $this->id, 'nama_barang' => $row['nama_barang']],
            [
                'submission_id' => $this->id,
                'nama_barang' => $row['nama_barang'],
                'image_path' => $myFileName,
                'jumlah' => $row['jumlah'],
                'harga_satuan' => $row['harga_satuan'],
                'harga_total' => $row['harga_total'],
                'keterangan' => $row['keterangan'],
            ]
        );

        if (! $submissionDetails->wasRecentlyCreated) {
            $submissionDetails->update([
                'image_path' => $myFileName,
                'jumlah' => $row['jumlah'],
                'harga_satuan' => $row['harga_satuan'],
                'harga_total' => $row['harga_total'],
                'keterangan' => $row['keterangan'],
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

How to fix the problem

Comment: I would recommend using the Laravel storage helper as you don't have to worry about using file paths, it just sorts it for you

Comment: Greetings @BenGooding, indeed. Full path is "storage\app\public\images\detail_pengajuan"

Comment: use storage_path() helper

Comment: It can be your server, some servers have the option for file_put_contents disable.